# Unbounded Geodesics and Nonpositive Curvature

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I have the following interesting(?) question:

Let $M$ be a complete Riemann manifold. Suppose that it is of non-negative curvature. I want to know if $M$ has unbounded geodesics.

As the question is stated right now, the answer is no - the flat torus is a good example. Therefore, we need to add some demands on $M$ for the answer to be yes.

1. Suppose we assume that the curvature on $M$ is not identically zero. Is there an unbounded geodesic on $M$?
2. Suppose that the curvature on $M$ is strictly negative. Are all geodesics on $M$ unbounded?
3. Suppose that $M$ is simply connected, and no additional assumption on the curvature of $M$ is made. Are some (all?) geodesics on $M$ unbounded?
4. Clear all the assumptions made in the previous subquestions, and assume that $M$ is non-compact. Are all geodesics on $M$ unbounded?

***Edit:*** Just to be clear , an unbounded geodesic is a geodesic which cannot is not confined in any bounded set - e.g. straight lines and geodesics in the hyperbolic space. Thanks to user8268 for adding the completeness demand.

Comment: what is an *unbounded* geodesic?

Comment: An unbounded geodesic is a geodesic which cannot is not confined in any bounded set - e.g. straight lines and geodesics in the hyperbolic space.

Comment: 1., 2. If $M$ is compact, no geodesic is unbounded, so curvature alone does not guarantee unbounded geodesics. 3. If you assume only simple connectedness, your metric might be incomplete, and there is no guarantee of unbounded geodesics. 4. Non-compactness is not enough for "all"; take a cylinder or similar product example. 5. Non-positive curvature, simple-connectedness, and _completeness_ get you "all unbounded" by the [Cartan-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) and the behavior of [Jacobi fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_field).

Comment: Posted the preceding as a comment rather than an answer, since I'm guessing "completeness" was intended...?